# Spring MVC 3 and returning validation errors to page from @Valid

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, spring-3, spring-annotations

I'm tired.  I've been working on a side Spring MVC project for the last two weeks and I've found the documentation to be misleading at best, and so I am now resorting to begging for help.  Sooooo..... Please help!

### The Question

What I am trying to figure out is why, with the below setup, the validation errors are not being sent back to the view, which is to say that the various `frm:error(s)` tags are not showing any errors.  I've checked the BindingResult argument to the POST request mapping via run-time debugging, and the errors are there.  Given the documentation is vague at best on this, can anyone point out my misplaced semi-colon or enlighten me as to what the secret sauce is that I'm missing to get the validation errors to the user to inform them of their personal inadequacies?

As a bonus, if anyone knows how to modify the automatic enum validation so I can add my own validation error message from the message bundle, I'd be much obliged.

Keep in mind that I'm trying to keep this purely Spring MVC 3.0.  I was pretty good with 2.5.6 but I barely used the annotations, so this project is just as much a learning exercise as anything else.  I'd like to go with purely 3.0 annotations and such, even though my brain is rebelling from the documentation which mocks me in my dreams and makes me want to just ditch the command object, set HttpServletRequest as my only RequestMapping argument, and have done with it.

### The Stack:

Spring 3.0.6
Tiles 2.2.2
Glassfish 3.1.1

### The Code:

**Spring app-servlet.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.facets.w101.almanac.spring"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
... other stuff
```

**Spring main.beandef.xml**

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
      p:basename="messages" />
<bean id="userValidator" class="com.mycmpny.UserValidator" />
... other stuff
```

**Controller code**

```
@Resource(name="userValidator")
private UserValidator userVldr;

@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(this.userVldr);
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/newuser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String newUserSetup(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("newUser", new User());
    return "newuser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/newuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView newUserSave(@ModelAttribute @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("newuser");
    mav.addObject("newUser", user);
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        return mav;
    }
    /* Code that saves user */
    return mav;
}
```

**JSP Code**

```
<frm:form method="POST" commandName="newUser">
<frm:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
<frm:label path="name">Name:</frm:label>
<frm:input path="name" id="userName" /><frm:errors path="name" /></td>
<frm:label path="type">User Type:</frm:label>
<frm:select path="type">
    <frm:option value="-" label="Please Select..."/>
    <frm:options />
</frm:select><frm:errors path="type" />
```

**Notes**

1. I tried to use `<mvc:annotation-driven validator="userValidator"/>` in the Spring configuration file to make the userValidator global per the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc-configuring), but for some reason the user validator was never found, loaded, or used.  I've tried configuring in the `[appname]-servlet.xml` and in my `main.beandef.xml` file, but no joy.  So I resorted to the @InitBinder scheme.
2. Apparently, if your request mapping does not have `BindingResult result` as a method argument, the whole validation thing blows up and instead of returning to the annotated request method, an exception containing the validation errors is thrown and Spring tries to send the browser to the 404 page. That you have to have BindingResult (or probably some other spring object) as an argument is (altogether now!) not documented.
3. Enums. It would seem if you use `frm:select` spring tag for a command object's enum data member and add the attribute-less `<frm:options />` child tag, Spring will automatically populate the drop-down select with options that have their value and text set to the enum's `getName` values. I have yet to find how to tie a custom resource bundle message to it.  This functionality is completely undocumented anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ModelAndView newUserSave(@ModelAttribute("newUser") @Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
.
.
}
```

Above should do the trick for showing the validation errors.